# How do i make a new photo album on my HTC Hero S

Tags: photos, gallery, htc-hero

I have Astro File Manager, but i still cant figure out how to create a new album in my Gallery.  If there is any way, can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new folder, and put some pictures in it. The Gallery app will detect and show that folder automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a folder with a bunch of images you surely do have albums in your phone.

Astro is a file manager (it focuzes on managing files,not on the aesthetics of the gallary); Gallery (default gallery app) would do the task.

but if you like, you can always try a light weight photo Gallery app **QuickPic** via this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder&hl=en) to arrange your albums nicely.